# Выбор библиотеки для пересылки сообщений API Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, поиск-библиотек

Мне нужно написать телеграм бота на питоне для отправки сообщений с одного канала на другой по ключевым словам. Для написания бота и установки параметров поиска в `JSON-файле` (канал для поиска, канал для отправки и ключевые слова) я использовал библиотеку `telebot`, но не нашел в ней методов для парсинга и отправки сообщений. Для парсинга и пересылки я создал модуль с библиотекой `telethon (TelegramClient)`, но создать в нем бота мне не удалось. В итоге мне сначала нужно запустить бота для установки параметров, а потом клиент для парсинга и пересылки. Также попробовал библиотеки `AIOGram` и `python-telegram-bot`, но столкнулся с вышеупомянутой проблемой. В итоге вопрос: есть ли библиотека для python с API телеграма, с помощью которой можно написать бота с методами парсинга и отправки сообщений?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.